# unable to ssh -T git@github.com

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am unable to ssh the git@github.com server. Here's what I am doing:

```
tutiwari@L-MAA-00800366:~/.ssh > ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tutiwari/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
```

It just waits after this output blocking the terminal. I have already generated the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys and copied the id_rsa.pub key to the ssh keys page in gihub.com
I am using Linux Mint with konsole if it helps.

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to log in interactively.

Comment: @tripleee I know that... but the terminal isn't suppose to hang at the output either. The output should end with this message: Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: @tripleee Neither am I able to git clone any projects on github.com via ssh. Although I can do it via HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  The next line of output in my trace is `debug: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5` so it looks like you are not connecting.  Do you have port 22 blocked?  Do you see anything in your firewall logs? Can you `telnet github.com 22`?

Comment: Is your private key encrypted with a passphrase?

Comment: @Cupcake my private key has no passphrase.

Comment: @tripleee yes I am able to telnet github.com 22 . Here's the output: 
 `tutiwari@chandler:~ > telnet github.com 22
    Trying 192.30.252.130...
    Connected to github.com.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    ^]
    telnet> `

Comment: If the remote server doesn't display the `OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian` etc banner, then you are not properly connecting.  The protocol dialog starts with a message from the remote server displaying this banner; if you are not seeing it then something on your end is blocking the banner (since it works for others).  This sounds like your firewall accepting but losing the packets, rather than outright rejecting.

Comment: @triplee Well temporarily I have switched to the Zsh shell and it is apparently working fine. Thanks anyway!